# Inaccessible host: `freetier.us-east-1.amazonaws.com' at port `undefined'. This service may not be available in the `us-east-1' region

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

I'm trying to call AWS Free Tier API from a Lambda function, but I'm getting this error:

```
Inaccessible host: `freetier.us-east-1.amazonaws.com' at port `undefined'. This service may not be available in the `us-east-1' region.
```

Free tier API documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/FreeTier.html

My code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

module.exports = {
    getFreeTierUsage: async (awsCredential) => {
        var freetier = new AWS.FreeTier({
            accessKeyId: awsCredential.accessKeyId,
            secretAccessKey: awsCredential.secretAccessKey
        });
        var params = {};
        let result = await freetier.getFreeTierUsage(params).promise();
        return result;
    }
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: @ArpitJain I tried including the endpoint param, but got the same error message.

Comment: According to the page you linked, the endpoint is: `https://freetier.us-east-1.api.aws`

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks, it worked fine with this endpoint. You can post as an answer if you want me to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like AWS is changing the URL format for their APIs.

Traditionally it would look something like:

```
https://freetier.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

However, the [Class: AWS.FreeTier — AWS SDK for JavaScript](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/FreeTier.html) documentation is showing it as:

```
https://freetier.us-east-1.api.aws
```

Need to include the endpoint parameter like this:

```
    var freetier = new AWS.FreeTier({
        endpoint: 'https://freetier.us-east-1.api.aws',
        accessKeyId: awsCredential.accessKeyId,
        secretAccessKey: awsCredential.secretAccessKey
    });
```